# Removing point in point cloud inside the boundary of another point clouds convex hull

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry, point-clouds, convex-hull

I have two point clouds pcd1 and pcd2. pcd2 is contained in pcd1, but I do not know the indices for the points describing pcd2 in pcd1. However the position of the object pcd2 represents is the same as it is in pcd1.
What I essentially want to do is remove all the points that represents pcd2 in pcd1, without using any kind of object recognition, ML/deeplearning. My thoughts were to compute the convex hull for pcd2, and then subtract all points in pcd1 located within the hulls boundary. However, I have not been able to find a way to do this.
I'm using open3d in c++ so that would ofc be a prefered solution, but a solution in python would also be of great help.
Hope anyone can help me :)

Comment: Did you try to implement a brute force solution using convex hull?

Comment: That is what if currectly trying to do :) However, I would ofc prefer a function call or something simpler/faster than just using brute force. I'm thinking that I could draw a line between a point that i know is outside the convex hull and every point in the point cloud. For each line I then check the number of intersections between the line and the convex hull. If the number is odd the point should be inside. However that is a lot of computation.

Comment: First get a working brute force solution implemented, then optimize. If you find that your solution isn't working, you can think another approach instead of wasting too much time optimizing and later realizing it was useless (for your goal).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is probably just to make use of a point in convex hull check to see if each point is within the two hulls. Then you can see which points are in both hulls.

Checking this in higher dimensions is not trivial, though. In the case of 2D hulls, you can check this in O(N log N) easily via using Monotone Chain Algorithm for convex hulls as a reference as you can just find the upper hull and lower hull (O(N)) then use binary search to see where the new point would be a hull point for the upper or lower hull (if so, it's not in the hull, if not, it is).

Brute force for generalized (higher dimensional hulls):

For each point, try adding it to the convex hull and see if it convex hull changes. If it does, it's not in the convex hull (though it could be on the hull...).